# Meteor HTTP.call gzip answer

Tags: node.js, http, meteor, gzip, inflate

I made a request to a server expecting to get a Json as an answer, but the answer was a compressed gzip and I don't know how to inflate this.

Does someone know a library or a native function to help me with this?

I tried `zlib` but that needs a stream and my request return a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact with the HTTP package of meteor I just have to make :

```
requestOption.npmRequestOptions.gzip = true
```

and the answer is uncompress by the library

Comment: It's a bit weird that it doesn't do this by default since the returned header states that it's content-encoding is gzip.  Either way, this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably ask the server to respond with JSON by adding the [HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) request header `{'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}`

```
HTTP.call('GET', url, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}, asyncCallback)
```

Comment: If i dot that, the server answer {failed : true}